# Why Reduce input records different with Reduce output records?

Tags: hadoop, reduce, records, mapper

I try to use mapreducer in python with library dumbo.
Below is my testing code for experiment and i hope i can receive all record from mapper to reducer output.

```
def mapper(key, value):
    fields = value.split("\t");    
    myword = fields[0] + "\t" + fields[1]
    yield myword, value

def reducer(key, values):
    for value in values:
        mypid = value
        words = value.split("\t")
    global count
    count = count + 1
    myword = str(count) + "--" + words[1]  ##to count total lines in recuder's output records
    yield myword, 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dumbo.run(mapper, reducer)
```

Below is the log of Map-Reduce Framework .
I expect the "Reduce input records" equal "Reduce output records" , but it is not . 
what's wrong with my testing code or i misunderstand something in mapreducer ? 
thanks.

```
    Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=405057
            Map output records=405057
            Map output bytes=107178919
            Map output materialized bytes=108467155
            Input split bytes=2496
            Combine input records=0
            Combine output records=0
            Reduce input groups=63096
            Reduce shuffle bytes=108467155
            Reduce input records=405057
            Reduce output records=63096
            Spilled Records=810114
```

it is work when modify reducer as below:

```
def reducer(key, values):
    global count
    for value in values:
        mypid = value
        words = value.split("\t")

        count = count + 1
        myword = str(count) + "--" + words[1]  ##to count total lines in recuder's output records
        yield myword, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect the "Reduce input records" equal "Reduce output records" , but it is not .

I'm not sure why you expect this. The whole point of the reducer is that it receives a group of values at once (based on the key emitted by the mapper); and your reducer only emits one record for each group (`yield myword, 1`). So the only way your "Reduce input records" would equal your "Reduce output records" would be the same is if each group contained exactly one record — that is, if the first two fields in each value were unique in your record-set. Since that's apparently not the case, your reducer emits fewer records than it receives.

(This is, in fact, the usual pattern; it's the reason the "reducer" is called that. The name comes from 'reduce' in functional languages, which reduces a collection of values to a single value.)